# подключить UnitTest в "проект"

Tags: php, composer, phpunit

Изучаю паттерны проектирования, прочитал о паттерне стратегия - решил закрепить практикой, скачал репозиторий https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/state.git
установил composer прописал там composer require phpunit/php-token-stream он накачал файлов каких то в vendor/phpunit
Давай приступать к разборке паттерна а тесты (демо) и не запускаются - D:\wamp\www\patterns\state\example\tests\ClosedDoorTest.php 
пишет Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found
Находил ответы - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065730/why-fatal-error-class-phpunit-framework-testcase-not-found-in попробывал не помогло.
Подскажите пожалуйста как нужно там подключать чтобы находило ети тесты?
спасибо.

Comment: Используется ли автолоадер компосера? ```require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';```

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста если я не подключаю новых файлов нужно ли там писать require.... ? просто хочу запустить уже существующие

Answer (score 1, accepted):

просто так взять и запустить тест нельзя.

1. вы можете создать файл phpunit.xml, указать в нем запускаемые тесты + указать bootstrap в виде "vendor/autoload.php". [Подробнее на официальном сайте](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html)
2. запустить phpunit указав ему опцию bootstrap `phpunit --bootstrap src/autoload.php tests/MoneyTest`. [Взято отсюда](https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html)

Так же, если вы скачали phpunit при помощи composer'а, то phpunit будет лежать в vendor/bin

Answer (score 0):

Ещё эта ошибка может быть вызвана использованием PHPUnit как минимум 9.5.27. При прописывания родительского тестового класса надо писать не "PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase", а "PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase".